# Detect on change event in hidden select option which is itself changed via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, onchange

I have built a dropdown which is styled and uses an unordered list.

Items from an array are populated to the select dropdown and the ul dropdown.

The user selects an item and it gets updated into a target span, as well as in being selected in the option.

However as this is all done via js, it is not able to actually fire the on change event for the select (as far as I can tell).

Is there someway to bind it to my other function?

Here is the html:

```
<div class="selectWrapper">
    <select id="townResult" class="dropdown" name="townSelect">
        <option disabled="" selected="" value="0">SELECT AN AREA</option>
        <option value="Second">Second</option>
        <option value="Third">Third</option>    
    </select>
    <span class="selected">Selected option</span>
    <ul class="townList"></ul>
</div>
```

JS/jQuery:

```
var popUkTowns = "[ FEATHERSTONE TOWN, ABARDARE, ABBEYDLE, ABBEYMEAD, ABBEYTOWN, ABBOTS LANGLEY, ABEDEEN, ABERAERON, ABERAMAN, ABERBARGOED, ABERCARN, ABERCHIRDER, ABERCYNON, ABERDARE, ABERDEEN, ABERDEENSHIRE, ABERDOUR, ABERDOVEY, ABERFAN, ABERFELDY, ABERFIELDY, ABERFOYLE, ABERGAVENNY, ABERGELE, ABERGELE  CLWYD, ABERLOUR, ABERSOCH, ABERTILLERY, ABERTRIDWR, ABERYSTWTH, ABERYSTWYTH, ABINGDON, ABOYNE, ABRIDGE, ABROATH, ACCRINGTON, ACHARACLE, ACKLAM, ACKWORTH]";
popUkTowns = popUkTowns.split("[ ").join(",").split("]").join('"').split(",");

var townList = $('.townList');
var townResult = $('#townResult');

for(var i=0;i<popUkTowns.length;i++){
    townList.append('<li>' + popUkTowns[i] + '</li>');
    //townResult.append('<option value="' +popUkTowns[i]+ '">' +popUkTowns[i]+ '</option');
}

selectOption = function(){
    var trigger = $('.selected');
    trigger.on('click',function(){
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
        return false;
    });
    var selectLI = townList.find('li');
    selectLI.on('click',function(){
        var thisLI = $(this).text();
        townResult.empty();
        townResult.append('<option value="' +thisLI+ '" selected="selected">' +thisLI+ '</option>');
        trigger.html(thisLI);
        var selectWrapper = $('.selectWrapper');
        selectWrapper.removeClass('open');
    });
}();

townResult.on('change',function(){
    console.log('Value changed'); // this doesn't work of course
});
```

I have a working js fiddle [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/djomeq3t/). Normally the select would be hidden, but for the purposes of this exercise I am displaying it in the fiddle to prove that the value is being updated in the select option.

I have tried to bind an on change event to the option as well as binding the `selectOption` function, but I cannot seem to trigger it, but there might be a better way to do this (ie when the `.selected span` has been updated).

Comment: You can call `townResult.trigger("change")`, but why do you need a change handler on a hidden element at all? Can't whatever that handler needs to do be triggered from the same code that updates the select's value?

Comment: Well I need a way for the select to be passed as a parameter to run a query on google maps API. If I can send the value in the select span, then great, but I assumed this would need an actual form value/input etc.

Comment: I don't understand. Why wouldn't you run the Google map query from the `selectLI` click handler?

Comment: I didn't think that would be possible. I have been looking at some of the js plugins that allow you to style dropdown selects as well as one custom one I worked on, and they all used a hidden select option to send data. But if I can do it via the selectLI, I will definitely look into it.

Comment: Those plugins use hidden selects because they are intended for generic use in forms that will get submitted. But I'm not telling you not to use a hidden select, I'm asking why you think you need a change handler attached to the hidden select? Even assuming you need to submit a form, again, your `selectLI` click handler can simply update the hidden select's value (as it already does) and then submit the form itself. (But are you in fact submitting a form to the Google maps API?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `trigger` the `change` event manually in the `click` event. Programatically changes are not going to trigger it automatically.

```
townResult.trigger("change");
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/djomeq3t/2/)**

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping it would be simple!